# What is the formula to find the optimum width and height of given units that would fit in an area?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

What is the formula to find the optimum width and the height of given units that would fit in an area? For example : 
I have 100 units that need to be placed in a rectangle that is 300 in height and 400 in width. How do I get the optimum width and height of a unit so that all 100 units can fit in the area?

Comment: Well the longest distance line segment entirely in the rectangle is the diagonal.  The diagonal cuts the rectangle into two right triangles.

Comment: You may want different units in your example.  100 < 300 so any shape will do.

Comment: I made some clarifications.

Comment: A mere suggestion: don't ask "what is the formula".Math is more interesting than that. Try to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your space has an area of
$$300\times400=120,000$$
This is the same as the combined area of all 100 units. Therefore, you have
$$120,000=100\times\text{Area of 1 unit}$$
Therefore,
$$\text{Area of 1 unit}=\frac{120,000}{100}=1,200$$
Now, you have to figure out one thing: What am I optimizing the height and with in relation to? You know that
$$\text{height}\times\text{width}=1,200$$
but you need to add another constraint to optimize the height and width. In this case, you want to optimize the perimeter (as you said in a now-deleted comment). You have
$$P=2(\text{width}+\text{height})$$
You then can write
$$\text{height}=\frac{1,200}{\text{width}}$$
and substitute that in to find
$$P=2\left(\text{width}+\frac{1,200}{\text{width}}\right)$$
All you have to do is find the extrema of this function within the range of acceptable values (for example, the function admits 1,000 as a possible value for the width, but that clearly isn't a valid solution, because one unit would be wider than the total original area!).

---

Putting it in a simpler way, if $h$ is the height, $w$ is the width, $A$ is the area, and $P$ is the perimeter, then
$$A=hw,\quad P=2w+2h$$
If you know either the perimeter or the area, you can optimize the other one.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient rectangle with maximum area per perimeter is a perfect square.  (Basic calculus.)  So if 1/4 of the units is less than the smaller side of the rectangle, that is best.  The square will slide right in.

If on the other hand  you can't do a perfect square because the smaller side of the containing rectangle is too small, The second best thing is a rectangle with the sides as near in length as possible.  So do a rectangle with one side equal to the smaller side of the rectangle.  That's as close to a square as you can get.

=====

So assuming 25 units is less than 300 inches.  Put this into a 25 by 25 unit square.  That gives you area of 625 square units.

If 25 units is more the 300 inches this is impossible.  So put it into a rectangle that 300 inches by (100 units - 600 inches)/2.  That's the best you can do.